# Xquery 3.0 group by attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

In my adventure to learn Xquery and Xpath I'm with a problem trying to group apples with their category.

I'm using **XPath 3.0**, and **XML 1.0** in my document.

I have this:

```
<fruits>

    <fruit>
        <name>Apple</name>
        <category>Summer</category>
    </fruit>

    <fruit>
        <name>Mondarine</name>
        <category>Autumm</category>
    </fruit>

    <fruit>

        <name>Kiwi</name>
        <category>Summer</category>
    </fruit>

    <fruit>
        <name>Aguacate</name>
        <category>Winter</category>
    </fruit>

    <fruit>
        <name>Banana</name>
        <category>Winter</category>
    </fruit>

</fruits>
```

I need the next output:

```
<summary>
<category = "Summer"/>
<item list-names = "Apple, Kiwi"/>
</summary>

<summary>
<category = "Autumm"/>
<item list-names = "Mondarine"/>
</summary>

<summary>
<category = "Winter"/>
<item list-names = "Aguacate, Banana"/>
</summary>
```

How can I do this with a XQuery?

Probably is very easy but I don't see it yet and I'm struggling a lot to solve this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in XQuery by iterating over the distinct values of category names, then querying the names of items that match the category using XPath:

```
for $category in distinct-values($fruits/fruit/category)
let $items := $fruits/fruit[category = $category]/name
return 
  <summary>
    <category>{ $category }</category>
    <item list-names="{ string-join($items, ', ') }"/>  
  </summary>
```

Note that your sample output is not valid XML:

```
<category = "Summer"/>
```

Your options for storing that value are either in an attribute:

```
<summary category="Summer"> ...
<category value="Summer"/> ...
```

Or in an element, which is what I chose for this answer:

```
<summary>
  <category>Summer</category>
  <item list-names="Apple, Kiwi"/>
</summary>
<summary>
  <category>Autumm</category>
  <item list-names="Mondarine"/>
</summary>
<summary>
  <category>Winter</category>
  <item list-names="Aguacate, Banana"/>
</summary>
```

Comment: No need for the curly braces in the body of the summary element

Answer (score 1):

As your subject line mentions XQuery 3.0 you could also use `group by`:

```
for $fruit in fruits/fruit
group by $cat := $fruit/category
return <summary>
  <category>{$cat}</category>
  <items list="{string-join($fruit/name, ', ')}"/>
</summary>
```